# SQL table design strategy for large amounts of location data with lots of inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, sql-server-2012

I'm designing an ASP.NET MVC web application that will be used to find where people are and map where they go from different apps. The system has the potential to have a large amount of location data for every user, about 3 months back for each user. I'm now trying to decide how to design a MS SQL 2008/2012 database for this.

Naively, there would be a table of location updates with following columns:

Id (int)

UserId (int)

Latitude (double)

Longitude (double)

Speed (int)

DateSent (datetime)

From my reading, it seems partitioning the table is the best way to accomplish this. If that's true, I'm a little confused on how it becomes automated to say divide the data in to partitions such as "today", "this week", "last week", "previous month", etc all the way down to having one large archive of everything that is just used for backup.

If I can provide any more technical requirements that might be helpful is devising a strategy let me know. I appreciate any insights from some database experts out there.

Answer (score 0):

note: not sure if you know this but table partitions are an enterprise feature which is pricey. you should make sure the amount of data justifies the upgrade.

a)you would want to partition the table based on a logical grouping for querying. "Today" "this week", "last week", "previous month" doesn't really make sense unless your queries are of those granularity. more likely would be keeping track of habits and changes in habits. eg. this month, last month, 3 months ago. then at the end of the 4th month, you would switch out the partition that had 3 month old data (which is now 4 month old data)

b) table partitions basically treat the partitions as part of a whole. once you setup the partition function and schema you won't need to worry about moving it and such. For instance if you partitioned it month by month keeping 3 months of data you would setup 5 filegroups. 1 for next month, 3 for the "current" months, 1 for the "old" month.

c) I highly suggest you don't keep a historical large archive of "everything" unless you NEED it. assuming these 3 apps are sending gps data every 10 minutes? thats 144 inserts per person per day or 4320 per month. or 51840 per year. I mentioned this was per person right?

I think you need to go back and think on the requirements for a bit first: how many people are you designing this for. whats the data you are looking to get out of storing this data... then design the database accordingly, THEN see if your design and requirements justify enterprise edition.